# Are numpy matrix chain multiplication optimized?

Tags: python, numpy

I used to use the `matmul` (`@`) operator all the time in `numpy`, but I recently found the function [numpy.linalg.multi_dot](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html), according to the docs

> uses optimal parenthesization of the matrices. Depending on the shapes of the matrices, this can speed up the multiplication a lot.

so given that `matmul` is a binary operator, I'm assuming it does not perform optimal parenthesization. Is this true? also, would it be possible to implement optimal parenthesization on a binary operator in python?

Comment: `multi_dot` only helps if the arrays differ substantially in shape.  Doing some of the dots first can substantially reduce the size of the problem.  When dealing with one `dot` (or a batch in parallel) that kind of optimization does not apply.

Comment: In `a@b@c...@d` the order is determined the python interpreter, not `numpy` or the operator.  It's up to you to write `a@(b@c)@d` if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably possible to write an array type that does optimal parenthesize of matrix multiplication. You could write an array that defers the actual multiplication process, returning a proxy object instead of an array containing the results. Only when some non-multiplication operation is attempted on the array, would the proxy do the actual multiplication (using optimal parenthesization). The tedious thing would be setting up the proxy behavior for the custom type, so that you can do the deferred multiplication before any other operation.

For example, here's a class that wraps around an array and queues up matrix multiplications, but only performs them when an indexing or slicing operation is attempted:

```
class DeferredMultiplicationArray:
    def __init__(self, *arrays):
        self.arrays = arrays

    def __matmul__(self, rhs):
        return DeferredMultiplicationArray(*self.arrays, rhs)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if len(self.arrays) > 1:
            self.arrays = [numpy.linalg.multi_dot(self.arrays)]
        return self.arrays[0][index]
```

This doesn't support lots of other operations that real numpy arrays do, so it's not a full solution, but it demonstrates the general idea of deferring the multiplication until the results are needed, so that you can queue up any further matrix multiplications you get. Here's how it would operate:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
>>> b = np.array([[3,4, 5, 6], [3, 2, 1, 0], [4, 5, 6, 7]])
>>> c = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
>>> d = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
>>> a @ b @ c @ d        # normal numpy matrix multiplication
array([[ 250,  500,  750, 1000, 1250, 1500],
       [ 370,  740, 1110, 1480, 1850, 2220]])

>>> A = DeferredMultiplicationArray(a) @ b @ c @ d
>>> A.arrays             # no multiplication has been done yet
(array([[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 4]]),
 array([[3, 4, 5, 6],
        [3, 2, 1, 0],
        [4, 5, 6, 7]]),
 [[1], [2], [3], [4]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])

>>> A[:]         # slice the array to make our class do the actual multiplication
array([[ 250,  500,  750, 1000, 1250, 1500],
       [ 370,  740, 1110, 1480, 1850, 2220]])

>>> A.arrays     # the result is now saved, not the inputs any more
[array([[ 250,  500,  750, 1000, 1250, 1500],
        [ 370,  740, 1110, 1480, 1850, 2220]])]
```